# PHP - FFMPEG - Unable to apply multiple regular expressions on media output

Tags: php, regex, ffmpeg

I am writing a php script (I have to use php) to cycle through a dir of media files and displaying media information in a chart.

Right now, I'm trying to do it on 1 file.

I can successfully do so. I currently can parse the output (using regular expressions) to obtain information such as file name, duration, resolution, etc

I was told that I can combine the regular expressions to make it more efficient.

When I do however, I am unable to parse the ffmpeg output correctly.

Consequently, I've tried copying the output to a string and parsing that using multiple expressions and it works just fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

---

### Working code

```
$media_info = "'test.mkv': Metadata: creation_time : 2011-03-12 09:04:18 Duration: 00:21:44.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 500 kb/s Chapter #0.0: start 0.097000, end 1304.107000 Metadata: title : 00:00:00.097 Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x400 [SAR 80:81 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default) Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default) At least one output file must be specified";


$file = array();
$file_test = preg_match_all("/'([a-zA-Z0-9\._]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*)'.* Duration: ([0-9]{2,}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]*)/", $media_info, $file);;
var_dump($file)
```

---

### Not Working Code

```
ob_start();
passthru("C:\\wamp\\www\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i \"{$videofile}\" 2>&1");
$raw_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


$ffmpeg_info =  explode("from", $raw_data);


$media_info = $ffmpeg_info[1];

$file = array();
$file_test = preg_match_all("/'([a-zA-Z0-9\._]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*)'.* Duration: ([0-9]{2,}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]*)/", $media_info, $file);;
var_dump($file)
```

---

### New Code

I tried using the ffmpeg-php extension and the following works (except for printing the bit rate)

```
$movie = new ffmpeg_movie($video_file);

echo $movie->getFilename();
echo "<br/>" ; 
echo $movie->getDuration();
echo "<br/>" ;
echo $movie->getFrameWidth();
echo "x";
echo $movie->getFrameHeight();
echo "<br/>" ; 
echo $movie->getBitRate();
echo "<br/>" ; 
echo $movie->getVideoBitRate();
echo "<br/>" ; 
echo $movie->getAudioBitRate();
echo "<br/>" ;
echo $movie->getVideoCodec();
echo "<br/>" ;
echo $movie->getAudioCodec();
?>
```

Comment: Are you able to use a library to extract the information instead of a regex on the output of a command line tool?  For example, http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: I am in the process of trying that extension

Comment: Just tried it. Only issue is that I cannot seem to print bitrate, everything else prints fine.

Comment: That's funny - hopefully someone who knows more about that extension will come along and answer.  Perhaps it would be better to post a new question about that problem?

Comment: It seems as though it is file dependent. I tried it on a different file and ended up getting a value.

Comment: Perhaps some files are encoded with a variable bit rate?  It's been a while since I ripped any MP3s.  For now I'll post my comment as an answer and see if anything else comes along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to use a library to extract the information instead of a regex on the output of a command line tool? For example, [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Yes, I am able to use ffmpeg-php extension to output the data

Comment: @ParthG, if this solves your problem, can you accept the answer?  If you've solved your problem another way, can you post that for posterity?  Thanks.